# document.getElementById().submit() not submitting

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

As stated in the title...for some reason I can't get the form to submit on click however it seems to be working fine for the other form I'm submitting on the same page. Am I missing something??

Here's my code on that portion

```
<form id = ".$i." name='edit_staff'  class='form-inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action = '/DTS/index.php/Index/editInfoStaff' method = 'POST'>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'surname' value = ".$surname." />";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'firstName' value = ".$firstName." />";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'middleInitial' value = ".$middleInitial." />";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'division' value = ".$division." />";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'email' value = ".$email." />";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'id' value = ".$id." />";
    echo "<a href = '#' onclick='document.getElementById(".$i.").submit()'/>Edit</a>";
    echo "</form>";

    echo "<form id = 'delStaff".$i."' name='delete_staff'  class='form-inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action = '/DTS/index.php/delete_info/deleteInfoStaff' method = 'POST'>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'surname' value = ".$surname." />";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'firstName' value = ".$firstName." />";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'middleInitial' value = ".$middleInitial." />";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'division' value = ".$division." />";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'email' value = ".$email." />";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'id' value = ".$id." />";
    echo "<a href = '#' onclick='document.getElementById(delStaff".$i.").submit()'/>Delete</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</form>";
    $i++;
```

Comment: what error you got while clicking delete link

Comment: Consider to escape your variables properly when you write them in HTML.

Comment: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: @Jack I tried making it like this: document.getElementById('delStaff".$i."').submit()  however it just displayed a syntax error instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update as below:
In first form:

```
echo "<a href = '#' onclick='document.getElementById(\"".$i."\").submit()'/>Edit</a>";
```

In second form:

```
echo "<a href = '#' onclick='document.getElementById(\"delStaff".$i."\").submit()'/>Delete</a>";
```

And try. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes around your id in

```
document.getElementById(delStaff".$i.").submit()
```

But the root problem is that you're abusing `echo` which makes it hard to deal with quotes. Supposing you want to insert quotes here, you would have to escape them :

```
echo "<a href = '#' onclick='document.getElementById(\"delStaff".$i."\").submit()'/>Delete</a>";
```

Instead of

```
echo "<a href = '#' onclick='document.getElementById(delStaff".$i.").submit()'/>Delete</a>";
echo "</div>";
```

you should have

```
<a href='#' onclick="document.getElementById('delStaff<?php echo $i;?>').submit()"/>Delete</a>
</div>
```

And of course, proper separation of the javascript and the html would be even better.

Comment: I tried adding single quotes on it but it said syntax error when I did

Comment: that line of code is actually a part of a big loop should I update the code including the whole loop??

Comment: The less lines wholly echoed you have, the easier it is to deal with that kind of problems

Comment: true...but my code is supposed to display the code in the question multiple times and the hidden inputs change every iteration...sadly I don't have a clue as to how to display it without putting it in an echo